# org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Please ensure that the type 'UserRestService' has a no-arg constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to create JUnit5 tests for Rest API.

```
@Test
public void resetRequest_NAME_AND_EMAIL_MISMATCH() throws Exception {
    when(userRestService.resetRequest(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(Boolean.valueOf("test"));

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/users/reset_request")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(ResetUserDTO))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andReturn();

    assertEquals(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "NAME_AND_EMAIL_MISMATCH");
}
```

Full code: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/test/org/engine/rest/UsersControllerTest.java#L187)

But when I run the test I get exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'userRestService'.
Please ensure that the type 'UserRestService' has a no-arg constructor.
.....
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Please ensure that the type 'UserRestService' has a no-arg constructor.
    ... 68 more
```

Rest service code: [GitHub](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/service/UserRestService.java)

I tried to add @NoArgsConstructor but I get warning that variables (UsersService userService, PasswordAdminResetHandler resetHandler and etc...) are not initialized.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you Spy the UserRestService? And to use @NoArgsConstructor you have to remove final on the specified member declarations

Comment: I received this code as it is. Is there a better way to implement this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do these two steps to resolve the issues

1. Try to use `@Mock` annotation instead of `@Spy` annotation
   OR
2. Remove `@Autowired` annotation from constructor as it's automatically injected. [Read this for more information ...](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/a7001be08c2df46db46d209d53bf86c809a85d3f/src/main/java/org/engine/service/UserRestService.java#L30)

Comment: Ok, Should I remove everywhere @Spe and replace it with @Mock?

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to create the Spy userRestService explicitly

```
@Spy
private UserRestService userRestService = new UserRestService(...);
```

and use created Spys or Mocks(as needed) as arguments

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you use @Spy on a class that has no no-args constructors.
So, it means you have to pass arguments, most likely mocks.
You have to use both `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks`. E.g.:

```java
@Mock
MyMockClass2 mock1;
@Mock
MyMockClass2 mock2;
@Spy
@InjectMocks
MySpiedClass spy;
```

The important thing is that dependencies are declared in the order that are required, otherwise Mockito doesn't have a mock/spy to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Remove final declaration from fields so that the default constructor becomes available for Mockito to use.

2) Provide a no-args Constructor (simply a constructor that does not take any parameters) and initialize the fields in question yourself.